# Does 1 Timothy 2:5 debunk intercession of the saints?

Tags: catholicism, new-testament, intercession-of-saints, 1-timothy

1 Timothy 2:5 says:

> For there is one God, and one mediator between God and men, the man
> Christ Jesus;

Does this mean that intercessions of the saints is not possible since Jesus Christ is the only meditator? I know Protestants cosnistently point to this verse to prove that intercession of the saints is biblical, but i want to know if this is true or not.

Comment: Hint: the answer to *most* questions of the form "Does <verse> disprove Catholic doctrine X?" is No -- Doctrine doesn't derive from individual verses but from holistic concepts

Answer (score 0):

Read this link if you want https://www.oodegr.com/oode/orthod/praktikes/agioi_pantes_1.htm . It is in Greek from a site about Eastern Orthodoxy , so you can translate it in English. It basically somewhere says that Saints are relative intercessors, Jesus Christ is the absolute intercessor. Eastern Orthodoxy is the true and correct faith. It is the same Church that was in the first centuries of Cristianity. It has Saints that even today do miracles and it produces Saints even today, like Saint Paisios, Saint Porphyrios and others who lived in the 20th century.

Read if you want about Mount Athos, which is a holy place and there are monks from Eastern Orthodoxy.